# Swagger ui URL is not working with external tomcat deployment

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, swagger

When I deploy the spring boot app with embeded tomcat, I am able to acces swagger UI using the below URL.

http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html

However, when I deploy the war file in external tomcat server, the above uri is not working. Thename of my war file is uam. so I tried with the below url as well

http://localhost:8080/uam/swagger-ui.html

Still it is not working. I am getting below popup.

Please advise, how to identify the url. I also do not know how to identify the rest api url when hosted via tomcat. There are no deployment errors.

[image: normal url]

[image: abnormal url]

Comment: Have you added @EnableSwagger2 annotation in your config class?

Comment: Yes.. All are added.. I have just one single class... As I mentioned, with embedded tomcat  it is working fine. Only with external tomcat, it is not working....

Comment: Have you added "/swagger-resources/**" in security config?

Comment: I am not aware of such config. Can you point out an example...?

Comment: Can you please take a look to the following comment:
https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/1996#issuecomment-335155187
Moreover can you please try to clear the browser cache?

Answer (score 1):

```
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

public class ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(MainApp.class);
    }

}
```

This solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

```
public class MdpApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {


    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder){
        return builder.sources(MdpApplication.class);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MdpApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

I write

```
@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder){
    return builder.sources(MdpApplication.class);
}
```

before main method, this work for me.